# How can I submit my site's URL to search engines?

Tags: seo, google, search-engine-indexing, bing, yahoo

I have a site but I cannot get its URL indexed in search engines like Google, Yahoo, Bing, etc... Please let me know how I can submit my site's URL to Google.

Comment: What's the URL for the site?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need to. Crawlers will find you on their own. However, if you would like to help that process a bit then include your domains in [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) and [Bing Webmaster Tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster). Both will provide you with a number of "helpful" stats on your site as well.

Also, make sure that you have an [XML sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en) on your site. It will assist the crawlers in moving through your website.

Comment: Really! But when I search for the same contents which is available at my site, then Google don't show my site in the search results.

Comment: How new is the site?

Comment: My site is 6 months old

Comment: So is you problem submitting the site or indexing it?

Comment: I don't know. But I tried to indexed it in Google but failed.

Comment: Did you try to submit in Google Webmaster Tools? What error did you get?

Comment: I do but it always says that "We get your request. Please wait it may take a few days to process it."

Comment: Is this where you try https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/?

Comment: Maybe. But I found that by searching in Google.

Comment: Well don't know how else to help you. Try https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Comment: Okay. I will try this and thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: Good luck. I update the answer with other links and instructions.

Comment: How can I make a sitemap?

Answer (score -3):

Try using http://www.google.com/analytics/, they'll provide a code spinet to insert on the head section of your website.

Comment: Just to be clear, Google Analytics isn't a tool for "submitting a site to a search engine". It is a tool for analysing site traffic.

Comment: Google Analytics won't help get your website found, crawled, or indexed by search engines.